# htaccess rewrite image URLs

Tags: .htaccess

How can i rewrite dynamic image URLs to their original origin?

Example url
/images/products/2658-14732-sergeant-dolly-jacket-olive-full.jpg

Real filename
/images/products/0002658/0014732_full.jpg

I now use a 404 page redirect to a php script but this uses a unneccesary amount of impact on the server and somehow blocks VPNs.

I came this far but can't find out how to add leading zeros.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^images/([a-z_-]+)/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-(.+)-([a-z]+).jpg$ /images/$1/$2/$3-$5.jpg [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(images)/(products)/([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)\-(?:.+)\-(full).jpg$ /$1/$2/000$3/00$4_$5.jpg
```

Do the zero's on these`0002658` `0014732` numbers change?

Comment: This is not the correct solution but brought me on an idea, this is what i've made of it

[code]
 RewriteRule ^images/(.*)/([0-9]{1})-([0-9]{1})\-(.*)\-(.*).jpg$ images/$1/000000$2/000000$3-$5.jpg
 RewriteRule ^images/(.*)/([0-9]{1})-([0-9]{2})\-(.*)\-(.*).jpg$ images/$1/000000$2/00000$3-$5.jpg
 RewriteRule ^images/(.*)/([0-9]{1})-([0-9]{3})\-(.*)\-(.*).jpg$ images/$1/000000$2/0000$3-$5.jpg
 RewriteRule ^images/(.*)/([0-9]{1})-([0-9]{4})\-(.*)\-(.*).jpg$ images/$1/000000$2/000$3-$5.jpg
 RewriteRule ^images/(.*)/([0-9]{1})-([0-9]{5})\-(.*)\-(.*).jpg$ images/$1/000000$2/00$3-$5.jpg

[/code]
etc